# Java: Method-level authorization check with custom annotation

Tags: java, security, annotations, authorization, aop

Has anyone successfully used custom annotations in Java to implement security checks or authorization on method-level? Something like this:

```
@AccessValidator(AccessLevel.ADMIN)
public void method(){...}
```

Or similar.

Is this possible, preferably without using Spring etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is AOP's job.

You can use either Spring AOP or plain AOP.

Take a look at this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

All you have to do is create annotation, and write a `@Before` advice and handle that kind of security in that advice. One code, work everywhere :D

Comment: What are you willing to do? Simple Spring AOP or plain AOP?

Comment: Plain AOP would be my go to.

Comment: Appreciate it. But this link is not about plain AOP, is it? It utilizes AspectJ.

Comment: AOP is the concept. AspectJ is one of the most popular framework implement full AOP specification (Spring AOP does not implement full AOP spec though)

Comment: I understand that. Okay, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Lasse, you are asking for sample code an do not provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) yourself, just a mini code snippet. Quite funny! And for "plain AOP" you need an AOP language or framework first. A simple OOP language does not know anything about AOP. As you said you wanted to be independent of Spring, AspectJ is your obvious choice.

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn: Your answer mainly consists of a link (so does your comment pointing to sample code). Answers on SO should be more than just that. And BTW, I think that security checks should not be done with `@Before` because only in `@Around` you can change the control flow, which you need to do if authorisation is rejected. In `@Before` you only could throw an exception in order to stop the target method from executing. If this is what you want to do it is okay, otherwise it is not the right advice type.